# A continuous function with a dense set of periodic points but without sensitive dependence on initial conditions

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

The Question: Give an example of a continuous function, $f$, on the interval, $I$, such that the set of periodic points of $f$ is dense in $I$, but f does not have sensitive dependence on initial conditions.

The Attempt: I tried using a trig function, so suppose $f(x)=cos(x)$. I am not entirely sure if I am supposed to define a set for I. However, I need to show that $cos(x)$ is dense in I but it is not sensitive dependent on initial conditions. Can you   give me some pointers or comments on how I can prove this?

Comment: How about the identity? :-)

Comment: Okay. I have not thought about that. I am just confused on how to define I. I just said let $x \in I$. Let A and J be sets such that $A \subset I$ Then, we can define $J=(x-\delta, x+\delta)$. We need to show at least one element of J is in A.  Since we have defined the identity function on I, no matter what element in J we pick, we can always evaluate it from the identity and it would be an element in A. I am not sure why this function would not make this set sensitive dependent.

Comment: $I$ can be anything, for example $[0,1]$. Every point is the periodic point. As for sensitivity, you'll need to look up the definition first. Also, this is not the first time I edited your "Can you help me with this" title. Read [How to choose a good title](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144).